# Remove element, but keep all data and events bind

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a container that could be injected in any specified container on the page (like a popup). Popup should have a button which deletes parent element. I tried using `.remove()` to delete parent element, however, it also removes popup and its events. I want it to remove popup (I still have the reference), however, I don't want `.remove` to unbind the events.

So far, I got this:

```
var popup = $('#popup');

$('body > div').on('click', function () {
    popup.appendTo($(this));
});

popup.find('button').on('click', function () {
    $(this).closest('div:not(#popup)').remove();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/volter9/0zms29g1/

Basically, is there a way to delete an element without removing its data or events?

Thank you for attention!

P.S.: I tried to append and hide popup in the body, but it's not what I need.

Comment: Essentially you seem to be asking for http://api.jquery.com/detach/

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use [.detach()](http://api.jquery.com/detach/)

> The [.detach()](http://api.jquery.com/detach/) method is the same as [.remove()](http://api.jquery.com/remove/), except that .detach()
>   keeps all jQuery data associated with the removed elements. This
>   method is useful when removed elements are to be reinserted into the
>   DOM at a later time.

Also you can append the detach element to the DOM by using the return value:

```
var div = $("div").detach();

$(div).appendTo("body");
```